# How is the match graph extracted from a stim.circuit.detector_error_model?

Tags: error-correction, stim, pymatching

Let's say we have an error mechanism `error(0.1) D7 D8 ^ D9 D10 ^ D13 D15`. I understand that Stim is trying to decompose the complex errors into graphlike errors. It is saying: ok, we have one error mechanism, when it happens, we have three edges `D7--D8`, `D9--D10`, and `D13--D15`.

My understanding is that: we are adding these 3 weighted edges to the matching graph. And these 3 edges are **dependent** on each other. Namely, if `D7--D8` is triggered, then we also know that `D9--D10`, and `D13--D15` is triggered.

However, it is not right. Because the MWPM decoder assumes **independent** probability of each qubit suffering an error (if I understand it in the right way), which means the weights of the matching graph should also be **independent** of each other so that we can add weights of edges that connect two defects.

My questions are the followings:

1. How does Stim convert a DEM to a matching graph with **independent** edges?
2. Let's say we have a DEM with two error mechanisms: `error(0.1) D1 D2 ^ D2 D3 ^ D7 D8` and `error(0.2) D2 D3 ^ D4 D7 ^ D7` . How does Stim deal with the weight of edge `D2--D3`?
3. Can we get the matching graph **with weights** in some way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does Stim covert a DEM to a matching graph with independent edges?

Stim *doesn't* do this. It's the decoder's job to turn the DEM into a matching graph. Stim tries to *help make this easier* by giving the suggested decomposition.

The key property that Stim uses when suggesting these decompositions is to notice pieces of the error occurring elsewhere. The idea is that if `D1 D3` can occur on its own from one single error, and `D2 D4` can occur on its own from one single error, then it must be safe to think of `D1 D2 D3 D4` as being built out of those two errors: `D1 D3 ^ D2 D4`. You need to be able to correct them individually, so you should also be able to correct them occurring together.

For example, suppose `D1 D3` is an X error in the bulk of the CSS surface code and `D2 D4` is a Z error on the same data qubit. The key thing to realize is that `D1 D2` and `D1 D4` and `D2 D3` and `D3 D4` **won't** appear from single physical errors in this context, because they require long strings of physical errors reaching from the bulk to boundaries, as opposed to single physical errors. So `D1 D2 D3 D4` will be decomposed into `D1 D3 ^ D2 D4` (decomposing Y into X*Z) instead of into anything else.

> Let's say we have a DEM with two error mechanisms: error(0.1) D1 D2 ^ D2 D3 ^ D7 D8 and error(0.2) D2 D3 ^ D4 D7 ^ D7 . How does Stim deal with the weight of edge D2--D3?

What *pymatching* does is to decompose `error(0.1) D1 D2 ^ D2 D3 ^ D7 D8` as if it were `error(0.1) D1 D2` then `error(0.1) D2 D3` then `error(0.1) D7 D8`. In other words, the big correlated error is seen as raising the probability of its component edges, and all correlations are ignored.

Pymatching combines edge probabilities `p1`, `p2` for the same edge into a combined probability `p1 * (1 - p2) + p2 * (1 - p1)`. Ultimately the combined edge error probability $p$ becomes a weight $w = \lg(p / (1 - p))$. Internally, weights are rescaled so that the biggest weight is $2^{24}-2$, then weights are discretized into even integers, so faster integer math can be used while matching.

Of course, simply ignoring the correlations is not *required*. Decoders that perform correlated decoding will take note of these correlations between edges instead of simply splitting them into independent pieces. There's a huge variety of ways this can be done. For example, [after a simple pre-matching pass that can only match adjacent detection events, the decoder can use the pre-matched edges as triggers for downweighting associated edges](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.09828).

> Can we get the matching graph with weights in some way?

Use `pymatching.Matching.from_detector_error_model` to ask pymatching to convert a DEM into a match graph, and then `pymatching.Matching.to_networkx` to get that graph as a `networkx.Graph`.

Comment: Thanks very much! That's very helpful!